# Numpy: How can I use last dimension of an array as a value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3-D array with shape `[1080, 1920, 4]`, the last axis stands for RGBA channels of a picture, and I have a dict mapping from RGBA values to int, I want to use `np.vectorize` to convert this array to a 2-D array with shape `[1080, 1920]`, how can I pass the array as a 2-D array with last dimension is a list to the vectorized function?

```
array = [[[112,  25, 235, 255],
        [112,  25, 235, 255],
        [112,  25, 235, 255],
        ...,
        [ 35,  35,  30, 255],
        [ 41,  40,  37, 255],
        [ 39,  41,  37, 255]]
        ...,
        [ 35,  35,  30, 255],
        [ 41,  40,  37, 255],
        [ 39,  41,  37, 255]]]
dic = {(35,  35,  30, 255): 1, (41,  40,  37, 255): 2}
np.vectorize(lambda x: dic.get(tuple(x)))()
```

what should I pass into the last `()`

Comment: Do you mean you need to flatten the 3D list into a 2D list, right, and pass it in the function, right?

Comment: `np.vectorize` is a glorified `for` loop. Are you open to other methods?

Comment: Sounds like `array.reshape(-1, 4)`.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `numpy.apply_along_axis`:

```
# Data with (3, 3, 4)
array([[[112,  25, 235, 255],
        [112,  25, 235, 255],
        [112,  25, 235, 255]],

       [[ 35,  35,  30, 255],
        [ 41,  40,  37, 255],
        [ 39,  41,  37, 255]],

       [[ 35,  35,  30, 255],
        [ 41,  40,  37, 255],
        [ 39,  41,  37, 255]]])

dic = {(112, 25, 235, 255): 0,
 (35, 35, 30, 255): 1,
 (41, 40, 37, 255): 2,
 (39, 41, 37, 255): 3}

np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: dic.get(tuple(x)), 2, array)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: `numpy.apply_along_axis` does work, but it seems to be slow, but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`vectorize` normally passes scalar values to the function. But you can specify a `signature`:

```
In [55]: f=np.vectorize(lambda x: dic.get(tuple(x)),signature='(n)->()')
```

Using @Chris example values:

```
In [56]: f(arr)
Out[56]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

But `vectorize` warns that `signature` use is slower:

```
In [57]: timeit f(arr)
178 µs ± 6.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Using `apply...` as @Chris does:

```
In [58]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: dic.get(tuple(x)),2, arr)
131 µs ± 1.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

and a list comprehension on a the 'flattened' array:

```
In [59]: timeit np.array([dic.get(tuple(x)) for x in arr.reshape(-1,4)]).reshape(ar
    ...: r.shape[:2])
35.3 µs ± 108 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The speed disadvantage of `vectorize` disappears with larger arrays, though I don't know if that applies to the `signature` case or not.